# Residual spectrum of a multiplication operator on $l_{\infty}$ and $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $a \in l_{\infty}$ and $$T: l_{\infty} → l_{\infty}, x↦ax$$. I was able to find that $\sigma(T) = \overline{\{a_n:n∈\mathbb{N}\}}$ and tried to find residual spectrum of this operator, however I'm unable to find it. Can somebody help me? Thank you!
I'm also wondering, what if we consider the same operator in $c_0$, where $c_0$ is a space of sequences converging to zero?

Comment: Remind us please, what is the residual spectrum?

Comment: @alepopoulo110 by definiton $σ_r(T) = \{a : T - aI$ is injective and $ran(T - aI)$ is not dense$\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $\sigma_r(T) \subseteq \sigma(T) \setminus \{a_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Vice versa, if $\lambda \in  \sigma(T) \setminus \{a_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then $T-\lambda I$ is injective and $(1)_{n=1}^\infty \notin \overline{ran(T-\lambda I)}$: Let $(n_j)$ be a sequence in
$\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n_j} \to \lambda$ $(j \to \infty)$ and $x \in l_\infty$. Then $a_{n_j}x_{n_j} -  \lambda x_{n_j} \to 0$ $(j \to \infty)$, so $\|(Tx-\lambda x) - (1)_{n=1}^\infty\|_\infty \ge 1$. Thus  $ran(T-\lambda I)$ is not dense. Thus $\sigma_r(T) = \sigma(T) \setminus \{a_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

If we consider $T:c_0 \to c_0$ then $\sigma(T)$ is unchanged but $\sigma_r(T)$ is empty: Again $a_n \in \sigma_r(T)$ is not possible and if $\lambda \in \sigma(T) \setminus \{a_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ then $ran(T-\lambda I)$ is dense: If $y =(y_n)\in c_0$ consider
$$
x:=(y_1/(a_1-\lambda), \dots, y_m/(a_m- \lambda),0,0,\dots) \in c_0.
$$
Then $Tx-\lambda x - y=(0,\dots,0, -y_{m+1},-y_{m+2}, \dots)$, hence
$\|Tx-\lambda x - y\|_\infty$ is small for $m$ sufficiently big.

Hope all is correct, please check.

Comment: What do you mean by $(1)_{n=1}$?

Comment: By $(1)_{n=1}^\infty$ I mean the constant sequence $(1,1,1,\dots)$. A common notation for a sequence $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ is $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be an accumulation point of $\{a_n\,:\, n\ge 1\}$ and $a\neq a_n$ for all $n.$ Then $a=\lim_ka_{n_k}$ for a subsequence $n_k.$ The operator $T-aI$ is injective. Its range is contained in
$$\{y\in \ell^\infty\,:\, \lim_k y_{n_k}=0\}$$
Thus the range is not dense. Summarizing the residual spectrum is equal
$$\sigma(T)\setminus \{a_n\,:\, n\ge 1\}$$
Concerning $c_0,$ for $a\in \sigma(T)\setminus \{a_n\,:\, n\ge 1\}$ the range $T-aI$ contains all the basic elements $\delta_n$ in $c_0.$ Therefore it is dense.